# How to run `source` with `docker exec`?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I wanted to source a file in a docker container running Ubuntu without going inside the container.

I used to:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
source FILE
```

Now I wanted to do:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID source FILE
```

and was surprised that the error pops up:

```
exec: "source": executable file not found in $PATH
```

True enough I realized that `source` does not seem to be your standard command, as I cannot locate it via `which source`. `ls` behaves nicely.

What kind of thing is this `source` command anyway, and how to execute it via `docker exec -it`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Source is not an executable ([source is a bash shell built-in command that executes the content of the file passed as argument](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do))

You should run source like this:

```
docker run --rm -ti _image_name_ bash -c 'source FILE'
```

Comment: ah! thank you! I forgot, docker is not executing commands with bash, but instead with sh.